# Why I can not interpolate string inside class definition?

Tags: string, swift

I can not do such thing inside class definition:

```
let parametersForFeedRequest = "?fields=type,id,created_time,description&limit="+"\(self.postsPerScreen)"
```

but code like this:

```
let parametersForFeedRequest = "?fields=type,id,created_time,description&limit="+"\(25)"
```

compiling well. Why?

btw: `parametersForFeedRequest` is class value-member.

Here is the code in the class (moved from the comments):

```
class FbFeedViewController: UITableViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var menuButton:UIBarButtonItem!
    let postsPerScreen = 25
    let parametersForFeedRequest = "?fields=type,id,created_time,description&limit="+"\(self.postsPerScreen)"
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more context for what you're doing? The code as-provided should compile fine as long as self.postsPerScreen is convertible to String and is accessible in that current scope

Comment: @ChrisC Yep, here:

   `class FbFeedViewController: UITableViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var menuButton:UIBarButtonItem!
    
    //...
    let postsPerScreen = 25
   //...
    let parametersForFeedRequest = "?fields=type,id,created_time,description&limit="+"\(self.postsPerScreen)"`

Comment: Oh, how can I put new line in minimarkdown?? Sorry

Comment: @drewpts edit your question and add it there :).
self is not defined in class pre defined variables

Comment: @DanielKrom
Ok, understood.
What I can do for workaround situation? Am I supposed to write "magic constants"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.postsPerScreen` is not available at class instantiation time (because `self` isn't defined until the instance has been initialized).  So, you can't define one property using the value of another.  To get around this you have a few different choices:

1. You could assign `parametersForFeedRequest` in an initializer.
2. You can use the keyword `lazy` to set up a closure that will initialize your property the first time it is accessed:

   ```
   lazy var parametersForFeedRequest: String = {return "?fields=type,id,created_time,description&limit="+"\(self.postsPerScreen)"}()
   ```

   By the time you access the property, the instance will be initialized and `self` will be available.  This will only initialize the property once.
3. You can define a *computed property* that will run each and every time you access the property:

   ```
   var parametersForFeedRequest:String {return "?fields=type,id,created_time,description&limit="+"\(self.postsPerScreen)"}
   ```

Comment: Thank you! Solution with closure seems very intelligent.